# xml file is not previewing anything.There is a message of android...ActionBarOverlayLayout

Tags: android, preview

When I open XML file in the android studio it shows a message android...ActionBarOverlayLayout without showing my image views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_select"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#2C2739"
tools:context="com.rcpl.cradview.Select">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/stu1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not work but worth a try.

Go over to your styles and in your parent write "base." before theme

Rebuild it and try again

Comment: In styles.xml It is showing Theme in Red color stating Cannot Resolve Symbol Theme.

Comment: Click on "Sync Project with Gradle Files"